# Perfect Server HTTP file "/" not found

Tags: swift, macos, swift2, xcode7, perfect

I have a problem when i launch the perfect http server.

> The file "/" was not found

I use Xcode 7.3.1 on MAC OS 10.11. I followed exactly the same steps in [this tutorial](http://www.chrismanahan.com/creating-a-web-service-swift-perfect)

This my screen message after executing the server
[image: This my screen message after executing the server]

Comment: Have you tried posting the question on the website where you found the tutorial?

Comment: Yeah, we can't fix a random tutorial from the web. You have to [edit] your question and include the relevant code if you want help.

Comment: it is a sample of using the PerfectServer that i found in git.

Answer (score 1):

In that tutorial, there is no default route, so you would need to make a request to /posts in order to get a response. If you work thru the tutorial, you will see how to post data to the server and retrieve a response.

Comment: Thanks for responding but the section building the service is suffisant for me. i don't want to interact with sql server. i want to pass different http command to get different http response through the GET and  POST. For exemple : if i send this command localhost:8181/posts/sayHello i get a http response "Hello"

Comment: There is a project called URL Routing in the Perfect Examples repository which shows several additional examples of route handling. Here is one suggestion of how you could set up your response:

Comment: `Routing.Routes["POST", "/posts/{request}"] = { _ in return PostRequestHandler() }

class PostRequestHandler: RequestHandler {
    func handleRequest(request: WebRequest, response: WebResponse) { switch request.urlVariables["request"] {
            case "sayHello"?:
                response.appendBodyString("Hello")
            default:
                 response.appendBodyString("request not handled")
        }
        response.requestCompletedCallback()
    }
}`
this will handle Posts to the path, Get will not be handled, you can leave that part of the route off to get both types

Answer (score 0):

For me the reason was:
I called the function not

PerfectServerModuleInit

but this way:
public func perfectServerModuleInit()

So perfect couldn't find it.